# C# Microkernel pattern example

Tags: c#, architecture, design-patterns

Does anyone have a simple but good explanation and possible
C# .NET classes or libraries either built in or 3rd party that is a good example of the Microkernel architectural pattern.

To me it is a bit vague and mostly looks like it is the classes that are at your lowest level of design. Yet we never call this the microkernel but rather our Core assemblies.

I'm battling to understand the relevance outside of an os kernel for example.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Microkernel analogy at application level in C# would be a main C# application (the micro kernel) which creates different app domains and loads different assemblies (kernel drivers services etc) in those app domain and communicate with them using IPC mechanism for message passing OR calling across app domain using Remoting (MarshalByRefObject). This will result in  the required isolation level that is desired in a micro kernel arch.